# Oracle gather statistics

Tags: oracle, statistics

I'm using Oracle 11g, and i have some questions regarding the statistics tables.

I used gather statistics (with 100% sample) and i saw a strange behavior. Here is values from the output statistic table for example:

```
Table_name | column_name | low_value |      max_value
  MyTable  |      A      |    30     |   393939393939393939
```

However, the next query gives my a different output:

```
SELECT MIN(A), MAX(A)
FROM MyTable

Output:
0    | 99999999999999999
```

How can it happen?
Please note that column A is `VARCHAR2`, while the values of this column are `INT` (nevermind why). Maybe the type issue is the problem?

Comment: As Giova answered, the low and high are RAW - the hexadecimal value `39` is the ASCII value of the character `9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the Statistics tab shows low_value and high_value using the RAW data type.

You can try in this way:

```
select 
    utl_raw.cast_to_number(low_value), 
    utl_raw.cast_to_number(high_value)
from cols
where column_name = '<column_name>' and table_name = '<table_name>'
```

regards
Giova

Comment: As the column `A` is a `VARCHAR2`, in this case try with `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2` instead.

Comment: Thanks both! Another question: If my data type is `varchar2` and i'm using gather statistics option, i should get the min/max by dictionary sorting or numeric sorting?

Comment: It will be by string sorting, '12345' will be smaller than '2'. It is a bad idea to store numbers in a `varchar2` as Oracle will treat it as characters always. The optimizer will have no way of knowing that '1' and '2' is very near each other - the optimizer will think that there can many values in between, like '12acDF56' or anything, really. Do not store numbers in strings, please. Your statistics will be much less useful and the optimizer will make more mistakes than if you store numbers in numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, the data is stored in a RAW format.  It's worth noting that the RAW value only stores the first 32 bytes of data.

In the example below the results are 100% accurate up to 32 bytes.  But I'm not sure if that's always the case.  In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992017/409172) I used optimizer statistics but they were not 100% accurate even for a few bytes.

```
--Create table, add test data, gather stats.
create table test1(a varchar2(4000));
insert into test1 values('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
insert into test1 values('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST1');
end;
/

--Find the low and high values.
select low_value, high_value
from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TEST1';


--Convert those values back to VARCHARs.
declare
    v_out varchar2(4000);
begin
    dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('4142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F505152535455565758595A414243444546', v_out);
    dbms_output.put_line('Low value: '||v_out);
    dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('6162636465666768696A6B6C6D6E6F707172737475767778797A616263646566', v_out);
    dbms_output.put_line('High value: '||v_out);
end;
/

--Note how these values are cut off.
Low value: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
High value: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef
```